# Docker invalid mode running airflow command

Tags: docker, airflow

I'm trying to use an Airflow Container. I'm using docker desktop and i'm running the following command on an ubuntu terminal

```
docker run \
> -ti \
> -p 8080:8080 \
> -v C:/Users/119302/Desktop/exemplo/01_dag.py:/opt/airflow/dags/01_dag.py \
> --entrypoint=/bin/bash \
> --name airflow \
> apache/airflow:2.1.2-python3.8 \
> -c '( \
> airflow db init && \
> airflow users create --username admin --password admin --firstname Anonymous --lastname Admin --role Admin --email aaa@gmail.com \
> ); \
> airflow webserver & \
> airflow scheduler \
> '
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /opt/airflow/dags/01_dag.py.
```

Where is my error since my file path is correct?

Comment: You said you are running on an Ubuntu terminal. Do you have the C:/Users/119302/Desktop/exemplo/ mounted as volume? Can you try escaping the path //c//Users/etc?

Comment: For escaping is just needed to user double `//` ? And how can I verify if the path is mounted as volume?

Comment: it depends. The -v option is the volume mounted in the host to the container. In your case, you want to mount a path which contains the 01_dag.py file to be used in the container. I suggest you take a look here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems

Comment: Yes, you are correct and the path is correct.

Comment: Using `docker volume ls` I verified that `/opt/airflow/dags/` doesn't exists.

Comment: Yes, but are you running docker commands on Windows? You mentioned you're running on Ubuntu terminal but the host path is a Windows directory C:/Users/119302/Desktop/exemplo/01_dag.py

Comment: I've changed `C:/Users/119302/Desktop/exemplo/01_dag.py` to `~/Desktop/exemplo/01_dag.py:/` and the Airflow service started. However, my dag is not listed in the Airflow UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem based off the error message was the docker volume path in the host and as we discussed you've got it working after changing it to:

```
docker run \
> -ti \
> -p 8080:8080 \
> -v ~/Desktop/exemplo/01_dag.py:/ \
```

Now, I suggest you to take a look at the official documentation in order to start up the webserver/scheduler and a better way to run Airflow with docker:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html